# String[] args parameter: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Hi i am a java learner and trying to make this program for add two number. 
While running this i am getting this error msg..

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at addnumber.main(addnumber.java:16)
>   Java Result: 1

```
public class addnumber{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x,y;
        int a,b,c;
        x=args[0];
        y=args[1];
        a=Integer.parseInt(x);
        b=Integer.parseInt(y);
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println(c);
   }
}
```

I know i can use Scanner class or string builder class however whats wrong with this code?

Comment: Did you pass in any parameters?

Comment: You need to run this code as: `java addnumber 3 5` i.e. pass 2 arguments on command line to avoid this exception.

Comment: Have you tried to check your params? Do you tried just debug program?

Comment: see the class name you have written addnumber make it Addnumber

Answer (score 1):

If you use the args-array you have to give the programm some parameters from outside for example from the console.

So open the console and go to the directory where the .java file is and compile it manually with

```
javac Addnumber.java
```

Now you should see a .class file there.

Than write a call like this:

```
java Addnumber 5 9
```

your arguments would be 5 and 9.

Also write the classname in capitals

Comment: Thanks kingalione.. I have one another problem. args[0] is for first argument and args[1] is for second one. So length will return me here 2 or 1?? and how can i get the last argument from this array??

Comment: use: 

args[args.length-1]

Answer (score 0):

If your running with eclipse or any other working tool. then you have to set run configuration-arguments.

Suppose you run this code in command line then you have to run this code using the below command

```
java addnumber 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Quastion, **The Problem** is in `String[] args`, this problem leads to find out what is the initial value of this Parameter as string? or in other words How is the IDEs call the main method? if you run this code in Netbeans or Eclipse by default will print this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

because by default the IDE call method with array of string with 0 length:

```
TheNameOfClass.main(new String[0]) // if you run it in some IDEs
>java Addnumber  // cmd with no args?
```

In your case the exception will occur in line `x=args[0];` because you invoke and you want to use some item in array out of range or grater than the length of the array.

Now you can configure it as example in eclipse to pass some Strings values as you need **OR** you need to compile and run the java class manual in a 'Command Prompt' and passed some of Strings values:

```
>javac Addnumber.java // compile it 
>java Addnumber 1 77  // run it and passs some values to array in main method
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one another problem. args[0] is for first argument and args[1] is for second one. So length will return me here 2 or 1?? and how can i get the last argument from this array??

Comment: In fact you want some reading on this subject [ARRAY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) , and then when you finish reading about array answer the question by yourself