# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in INTELIJ

Tags: java, exception

I just started learning java, and I created a support code (called HELP) to help me track some variables in another code im writing. But when I try to run HELP I get this exception in return, can someone help me?

Im using INTELIJ

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int T = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);



    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        //bob vê a carta
        int see;
        int unseen;
        if (Math.random() > .5) {
            see = a;
        } else see = b;
        System.out.println(see);
    }

}
```

the output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at HELP.main(HELP.java:4)
```

Comment: I suppose you didn't pass any argument while executing this code. Hence, you must be getting this error while assigning value to variable a

Comment: yeah, it what that XD. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String\[\] args parameter: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007178/string-args-parameter-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying any arguments when you run the program so args[0], args[1], args[2] isn't a valid index.
In one old post founded this
// to use 10 when there aren't args...

> int trials = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 10;