# How can I fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 error in my program below?

Tags: java, input, error-handling

I am just a beginner in java and I copy-pasted this little program from my textbook, so it's completely right. This error keeps occurring every time. How to fix it?
[[image: 1]]

Comment: Click on the link to see the image of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String\[\] args parameter: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007178/string-args-parameter-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: Do not post the code or error as image, post it as text

Answer (score 1):

The `args[]` is an array containing arguments passed to the program at launch, in your case nothing has been passed, which means `args[]` is empty.
And since, selecting [0], [1] or any value will generate an error.

**Edit** :

To "fix" your error, you will have to either initialize `a` and `b` directly
For example :

```
int a = 2; 
int b = 4;
```

**OR**
Use a `Scanner` to let the user choose the values :

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
```

**OR**
Pass some arguments to your main method :

> java hello 2 4

`2` and `4` are `args[0]` and `args[1]` respectively.