# Eclipseerror while doind problem of if and else

Tags: java, loops

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at newfreecode2.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

this error comes in while my code is

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int mark=Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
        if (mark>=50) {
            System.out.println("pass");
        } else {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }   
    }   
}
```

i dont get what this error actually means i m new in java still learning could you help me please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: while you are ruining your program, are you passing the parameter ? Might be that is causing the problem.

Comment: that is not an "*Eclipseerror*" (as mentioned in the title) but just an "*ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*" (asked very often on this site) -- that happens if you code something like `args[0]` but the array does not have that element, that is, the index is out of bounds (negative or too large). In this particular case, the array is empty (program started without any arguments)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String\[\] args parameter: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007178/string-args-parameter-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) Alternatively, you might want to check [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373328/10871900)

Comment: what should i do for it? @user85421

Comment: 1) before accessing the array, check if it has enough elements (`args.length`), printing an error message (usage) if not; and 2) provide the required arguments when starting the program

Comment: i did all in earliear program above. same program run in cmd working ok but not in eclipse ,whenever i run a program there is a pop up occcure  in eclipse asking again to run and then this above error occure 
@developer-vivekjain

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have String Args simple get he users input via scanner and check if it is passed or fail.

> Refer the below working exaple [here](https://onlinegdb.com/s9ReZ4gzBV).

Sample code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mark =0;
        
        Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter the value =");
        mark = sn.nextInt();
  
        if (mark>=50) {
            System.out.println("pass");
        } else {
            System.out.println("fail");
        }   
    }   
}
```